# I'm trying to automatically reload a div after some seconds but it doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: ajax, html, reload, seconds

Here is the Main code. Please check it. what is making this conflict.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
{
  setInterval(function() 
  {
    $.get("ajax_files/manage_friend_requests.php", function (result) 
    {
      $('#all_friends_requests').html(result); // This is the div i am reloading again and again after some seconds.
          });
        }, 9000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: By not working, what do you mean? Does `result` return something on Chrome?

Comment: The div doesnot reload on Chrome. But its properly reloading on Firefox and I.E 10

Comment: What's in `result` when you are on Chrome? I am assuming that this is correct. Also, does `#all_friends_requests` is created dynamically or already part of the DOM when the document is ready? Otherwise, try `$.ajax` to see if it's more reliable in your situation.

Comment: Its a dynamic Php content which contains users and there images in the form of Table. Well now i have noticed something, it sometimes start working on Chrome, but mostly it do not work. I am totally confused whats going on here, because its working totally fine on Firefox and I.E

Answer (score 0):

You should be safer with something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "ajax_files/manage_friend_requests.php"
        }).done(function(result) {
            var $friends_requests = $('#all_friends_requests');
            if ($friends_requests.length > 0) {
                console.log('Received: '+result);
                $friends_requests.html(result);
                console.log('UPDATED friends requests');
            } else {
                console.log('CANNOT access friends requests container');
            }
        });
    }, 9000);
});
```

Depending on what the console will display, you will probably put the issue in evidence.